# Are relations necessary in mysql / phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I can create relations/foreign keys in phpmyadmin/mysql. My question is...is it necessary? Is it mainly just for my flow-chart / organization / notes..or does it actually help the database in performance?

Also, when I export the database to an sql file, I don't see mention of the relations anywhere...how would mysql recover them if I reloaded the database from this file?

Thanks

Comment: Please see [Wiki: RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDBMS) -- they are called a *Relational* Databases for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Relations between tables aren't for performance -- they're for minimizing duplicated data, and implementing business rules.

mysqldump files include the relationships - they're called foreign keys, and are identified by the FOREIGN keyword.

Answer (score 0):

i'm use `ERwin` or `Nevron diagram` for make some relations in DB.

by using it, we can analize some relation. so we can prevent any mistake in each relation.